# How to perform Shapefile to Raster with ArcMap 10.1 while preserving resolution and values?

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.1, shapefile, arcgis-desktop, point

I am new to ArcMap and I would really appreciate some help. I want to create a new raster using a value in a column of a point shapefile.
I have a point shapefile with points equally spaced and each placed at the center of each pixel of a raster layer. (I created this shapefile using 'Raster to point' tool)
Now I want to create a raster with the same resolution of the original raster but using as value the values of column in the shapefile table. How can I do that?

I tried running 'Point to raster'(black squares)but it's not doing what I am looking for.

[image]

This is what happens running 'point to raster' setting the cell size as the original raster:
[image: cell size set equal to original raster]

Comment: Did you try to set the cellsize to your original raster when running the Point to Raster tool (select the original raster file in the 'Cellsize (optional)' box)? Furthermore, you can set a 'Snap Raster' in the environment settings of the tool. Therefore, click 'Environments...', head to 'General Settings' and scroll down to 'Snap Raster'. Again, set your original raster file here. This should ensure that your new raster snaps to the original one.

Comment: Hi David, the second image shows what happens if I set the Cellsize to 2m(= original raster resolution)

Comment: setting the 'snap raster' should work for you. as @David says above

Comment: Did you set the cellsize manually (2m) or did you select the original **file** (clicking the folder symbol and browsing to your original file)? Make sure you also set the Snap Raster in your Environment settings as suggested above!

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to provide us with more precise instructions as to what you did and where the software behaviour you observed started to deviate from what you expected, please?  At the same time try to cover off on the clarifications requested in these Comments too.